# Finding nearest dates in SQL

Tags: sql, date

I know that there are some threads on this subject, however, my query is slightly different to what I've seen and the solutions presented before don't seem to be working for me.
I have two tables, X and Y, here simplified to one ID, in fact of course I have multiple IDs. The period category lasts from the Date given to the beginning of the next period.

```
ID  Date        Period
A   12/01/2010  1
A   12/03/2010  2
A   15/06/2010  3
A   17/08/2010  4
A   20/10/2010  5
```

and

```
ID    SampleDate
A     20/01/2010
A     25/01/2010
A     21/11/2010
```

What I need to get is:

```
ID    SampleDate   Period
A     20/01/2010   1
A     25/01/2010   1
A     21/11/2010   5
```

I've tried this:

```
    with cte as
(
select
    Y.ID,
    Y.sampleDate,
    X.Period,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by Y.ID, Y.sampleDate order by DATEDIFF(day,X.Date, Y.sampleDate)) as DaysSince

from X
left join Y
on X.ID=Y.ID
)

select ID,
sampleDate,
Period
from cte
where DaysSince=1
```

This produces the correct size of the table, but instead of giving the perspective periods for the samples, it just prints out the top period number for all of them (for a given ID).
Any idea where I'm making a mistake?

Comment: are those sampledate fields date/datetime fields? If they're strings, then `datediff` is going to barf.

Comment: Sorry, I should probably explain. The dates in my file are smalldatetime, the above is just an example. The IDs are varchar, and Period is int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in your query that removes entries with negative datediff, so if you add that to the join:

```
    with cte as
(
select
    Y.ID,
    Y.sampleDate,
    X.Period,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by Y.ID, Y.sampleDate order by DATEDIFF(day,X.Date, Y.sampleDate)) as DaysSince

from X
left join Y
on X.ID=Y.ID and X.Date < Y.sampleDate  /* skip periods after the one we're interested in */
)

select ID,
sampleDate,
Period
from cte
where DaysSince=1
```